# Excel range lookup based on date and sum values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with dates and payment amounts.
On another table I calculate my monthly outgoings split by date and going off into the future for a budget plan
How do I get value from table 1 based on the future date. eg, Jan 2024 I'd be paying for subcriptions started in 2015, 2020 . but in March 2024 I'd be paying for 2015,2020 and 2024

| Name | Value | Date started (mm,yy) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMAZ | 100.00 | 1/15 |
| DSNY | 500.00 | 6/20 |
| NTFX | 250.00 | 3/24 |

2024 budget forecast

| month (mm,yy) | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1/24 | 600 |
| 2/24 | 600 |
| 3/24 | 850 |
| 4/24 | 850 |

I can get a value if the forecast date is > subscriptions date but I can't figure out how to apply it to a range and get the sum from that range

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _lastRow,MATCH(1,1/($C$2:$C$4<E2)),
     _dateStart,$C$2:INDEX(C:C,_lastRow),
     @SUMIFS($B$2:$B$4,$C$2:$C$4,">="&_dateStart,$C$2:$C$4,"<="&E2))
```

---

Make sure to change the cell reference and ranges accordingly as per your suit.

---

Or, you can use this one as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$4,$C$2:$C$4,
        ">="&INDEX($C$2:$C$4,MATCH(1,1/($C$2:$C$4<E2),-1)),
        $C$2:$C$4,"<="&E2)
```

---

Or, using <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> with <kbd>SUMIFS( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$4,$C$2:$C$4,
        ">="&XLOOKUP(1,($C$2:$C$4<=E2),$C$2:$C$4,,1,2),
        $C$2:$C$4,"<="&E2)
```

---

You can also spill the output if you are using MS365, with a single dynamic array formula.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _d, $C$2:$C$4,
     MAP(E2:E5,LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS($B$2:$B$4,_d,">="&XLOOKUP(1,(_d<=x),_d,,1,2),_d,"<="&x))))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
I got a working formula and I've pasted it below as an image

[image: Working date range formula]

Comment: By that formula i don't think you will get `850` for `3/24`

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
=SUMIFS([Value],[Date started (mm,yy)],"<="& [month (mm,yy)])
```

Which [Value] = B:B and [Date started (mm,yy)] = C:C

Then put the month in it, example:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,"<="&G3)
```

[Example Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcG7B.png)